# EntityFramework update Many to Many without materializing the collection

Tags: c#, .net, many-to-many, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I have linked 2 Entities `Project`, `Train` with a many to many relationship.
Now, I want to add an existing `Train` to `Project.Trains`. Unfortunately, the collection has a lot of entries. When I write `project.Trains.Add(...)` it materializes the complete collection and this takes a lot of time. Is there a way to tell EF that I want to add the Train to the Project without materializing the collection, so that the action is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Train.Projects` collection will have *fewer* items than its `Project.Trains` counterpart, a quick solution would be adding the `Project` to the `Train` instead of the other way around:

```
train.Projects.Add(project);
```

Comment: Thx, my question just mentioned one case. In our project, it is a generic function that uses Reflection to access the properties, so finding the back reference is not so easy. But for now, we implement this case as special case and go on with the generic version for all other entities. If we end up with too many special cases, we will definitely give @roland s solution a try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way of doing it, but it is very difficult, and it involves digging into the very interna of EF. If you use the proxies generated by EF, they will typically implement `IEntityWithRelationships`. You will be able to access the relationship manager as

```
var entityWithRelationships = project as IEntityWithRelationships;
var relatedEnd = entityWithRelationships.RelationshipManager.GetRelatedEnd("RelationshipName as found in Metadata");
```

With this setup you should be able to add the `Train` as follows:

```
context.Trains.Add(train);
relatedEnd.Add(train);
```

As said, it is a long way to make it work, but it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1- Turn off lazy loading. This way, accessing `Trains` doesn't make a
    query to DB. But be aware of the side effects because you may have
    already relied on it.

2- Close to Relational Database world: Add FK property to `Train` entity and set it on the newly created
    object:

```
    newTrain.ProjectId = project.Id
```

3- Even more Close to Relational Database world: Add [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) of ProjectTrain, to implement Many-to-Many relation

```
   public class ProjectTrain
   {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public Project Project {get;set;}
        public Train Train {get;set;}
   }
```

and add this to the context:

```
DBSet<ProjectTrain> ProjectTrains {get;set;}
```

and finally, make a new entity of `ProjectTrains` and set the `Train` and `Project` properties